# Exporting QGIS project using qgis2web

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis2web

I am trying to export my QGIS project using the QGIS2WEB extension. I selected the OpenStreetMap but nothing shows up except for the points I made.

Do you have any idea why that was the case?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'selected the OpenStreetMap'? Is nothing showing up in the qgis2web preview window?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, make sure that you have followed the steps in the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRD19qBzojo&ab_channel=Q-tips

1. Don't forget about the **"Update preview"** next to the **"Export"** option, which is always available in the bottom left corner of your QGIS2Web interface.
2. Usually, if it's something up, the preview should throw nothing or at least an incomplete map with missing layers.
3. If happens something like this, please **check all the layers separately** by thinking of the boxes. When, for example, your map includes 7 layers (all of them should come out in your "Layers and Groups" section", start making **"Preview"** by selecting 1 of them then 2/7 3/7, and so on until you encounter the situation, where the preview on your right is blank.
4. If you find the layer, which causes an error I would advise you to visit the given layer **"Properties" -> "Fields"** where you can check especially the symbols used in the field titles (your data attribute column names). If you have something like "`&`", then QGIS2web source code throws an error, which finally results from the lack of preview and lack of some layers in your map.
5. If you want to have the OpenStreetMap canvas, then in your QGIS project go to the **"Browser"** panel, which should appear on your left, next select the **"XYZ Tiles"** and pick up "OpenStreetMap" from there, which should be the only one option available as a default.